# Running dot -Tpng test.dot -o test.png results in a segfault

Tags: graphviz

I am a bit desperate about what I'm doing wrong. I have installed graphviz 3.0.0 on Mac OS Catalina via homebrew.

test.dot:

```
graph g {
        a -- b ;
}
```

running `dot -Tpng test.dot -o test.png` results in a segfault. What's wrong about my invokation to dot?

The output of `dot -vtest.dot` is:

```
dot - graphviz version 3.0.0 (20220226.1711)
libdir = "/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/3.0.0/lib/graphviz"
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_dot_layout.6.dylib
Using layout: dot:dot_layout
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_core.6.dylib
Using render: dot:core
Using device: dot:dot:core
The plugin configuration file:
    /usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/3.0.0/lib/graphviz/config6
        was successfully loaded.
    render  :  cairo dot dot_json fig gd json json0 map mp pic pov ps quartz svg tk visio vml vrml xdot xdot_json
    layout  :  circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp twopi
    textlayout  :  textlayout
    device  :  bmp canon cgimage cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot dot_json eps exr fig gd gd2 gif gv icns ico imap imap_np ismap jp2 jpe jpeg jpg json json0 mp pct pdf pic pict plain plain-ext png pov ps ps2 psd sgi svg svgz tga tif tiff tk vdx vml vmlz vrml wbmp webp xdot xdot1.2 xdot1.4 xdot_json
    loadimage   :  (lib) bmp eps gd gd2 gif jpe jpeg jpg pdf png ps svg webp xbm
pack info:
  mode   undefined
  size   0
  flags  0
  margin 8
pack info:
  mode   node
  size   0
  flags  0
zsh: segmentation fault  dot -v test.dot
```

The output of `dot -v test.dot` looks the same, at first glance.

Comment: Try: `dot -v -Tpng test.dot -o test.png`  (this seems to work on my Windows install ...)    (`dot -vTpng test.dot -otest.png` seems to do something different)

Comment: @Luuk Causes no difference.

Comment: Ok, I am having same version, and in stead of `segmentatin fault`, I am getting `flags  0
fontname: "Times-Roman" resolved to: (ps:pango  Times,  REGULAR) (PangoCairoCoreTextFont) "Times 14"...`  . Maybe re-install (or check installation) of graphviz ?  (tested on MacOS now)

Comment: What happens with: `dot test.dot` or `dot -v test.dot`?

Comment: @sroush The same, see edit.

Comment: Intuition (not knowledge) makes me think it is a "font" problem (see Luuk's comments).  Add this **node[label=""]** before the edge, and try dot again.  Maybe open an issue here: https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues

Comment: @sroush You were right; this did pass. I have opened an issue.